# SQL Update fails - pyodbc - informix

Tags: python, informix, pyodbc

Updates to an informix database via a python script using pyodbc are silently failing.

I am using the syntax as provided in the pyodbc wiki and tried manual commit as well as autocommit

```
   cursor= conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("update eqpt set notes='BOB' where serialno='SAM'") 
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
```

I posted this question in the pyodbc group as well but unfortunately did not get an answer.

Comment: In what sense are they failing?  Do you have an item in `eqpt` with serial number of `'SAM'`?  How does pyodbc signal failure?  There is no test visible in the code shown.  Why would you need a cursor on your update statement (which may show my almost complete lack of knowledge of pyodbc)?  It is a singleton statement that simply needs to be executed.  Does a cursor need to be opened before it does anything?

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. Check how many records was changed (it is retured by `execute()`), and how many records should be changed (using `SELECT count(*) ... WHERE...`:

   ```
   cursor= conn.cursor()

   rs = c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM eqpt WHERE serialno='SAM'")
   for txt in c.fetchall():
       print('before %s' % (txt[0]))

   rows_affected = cursor.execute("update eqpt set notes='BOB' where serialno='SAM'") 
   print('rows_affected: %d' % (rows_affected))

   rs = c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM eqpt WHERE serialno='SAM'")
   for txt in c.fetchall():
       print('after %s' % (txt[0]))

   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
   ```
2. You can enable ODBC tracing and check what is returned by ODBC driver.